# How to get and set attribute value from BsMultiSelect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bsmultiselect

Currently, I'm working on bsMultiselect library. I want to set a new attribute value on bsmultiselect and get that attribute value on button click.

a Html:

```
   <div id="languages1-id"></div>
```

JS:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var options = [
  { text: "text1", myattr: "text1", selected: true, disabled: false, hidden: false },
  { text: "Lorem ipsum", myattr: "Lorem ipsum", selected: false, disabled: false, hidden: false },
  { text: "text3", myattr: "text3", selected: false, disabled: false, hidden: false },
  { text: "Lorem ipsum", myattr: "Lorem ipsum", selected: false, disabled: false, hidden: false },
  { text: "text5", myattr: "text5", selected: true, disabled: false, hidden: false },
  { text: "Lorem ipsum", myattr: "Lorem ipsum", selected: false, disabled: false, hidden: false }
];


var languages1 = null;

var $languages = $('#languages1-id')

var callMs = function (id, process) { return $(id).each(function (i, e) { let ms = $(e).data("DashboardCode.BsMultiSelect"); if (ms) process(ms); }) }

var getIsAttached = function () { return $languages.data("DashboardCode.BsMultiSelect") != null }
var disabled = false;
var disabledOptions = false;
var install = function () {
  $languages.bsMultiSelect({
    options: options,
    getDisabled: function () { return disabled },
    getIsOptionDisabled: function (o) { return o.disabled },
    getIsOptionHidden: function (o) { return o.hidden }
  });

}
install();
$('#btnAttach').click(
  function () {
    if (getIsAttached()) {
      $languages.bsMultiSelect("Dispose");
      $languages.unbind();
    }
    else {
      install();
    }
  }
);

$('#btnDisable').click(
  function () {
    if (getIsAttached()) {
      disabled = !disabled;
      $languages.bsMultiSelect("UpdateDisabled");
    }
  }
);

$('#btnDisableOptions').click(
  function () {
    if (getIsAttached()) {
      disabledOptions = !disabledOptions;
      $languages.bsMultiSelect("UpdateOptionsDisabled");
    }
  }
);

$('#btnRemove').click(
  function () {
    var inputValue = $("#inputValue").val();
    if (inputValue) {
      var position = -1;
      for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var item = options[i];
        if (item.text.toLowerCase() == inputValue.toLowerCase()) {
          position = i;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (position >= 0) {
        options.splice(position, 1);
      
        if (getIsAttached()) {
          callMs('#languages1-id', function (ms) { ms.updateOptionRemoved(position) })
         
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
$('#myaction').click(
  function () {
    var x = $('#languages1-id').bsMultiSelect('GetContainer');
    console.log(x);
  }
);
$('#btnAddSelected').click(
  function () {
    console.log("add");
    var inputValue = $("#inputValue").val();
    if (inputValue) {
      var position = -1;
      for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var item = options[i];
        if (item.text.toLowerCase() == inputValue.toLowerCase())
          return;
        else if (item.text.toLowerCase() > inputValue.toLowerCase())
          break;
      }
      position = i;
      if (position >= 0) {
        options.splice(position, 0, { text: inputValue, selected: true, disabled: false, hidden: false });
      
        if (getIsAttached()) {
          let ms = $('#languages1-id').data("DashboardCode.BsMultiSelect")
          ms.updateOptionAdded(position);
      
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Get value:

```
var itemName=[];
var attrData=[];

$('#languages1-id input:checked').each(function() {
    itemName.push($(this).next().text());
    attrData.push($(this).next().attr('myattr'))
});
```

Output:
**itemName** Array `['text1', 'text3']`
for the text is working fine!

**attrData** Array `['undefined','undefined']`
But for attribute, it's not working.

How can I get attribute value? Thanks.